# How to programmatically clear library info definition?

Tags: hooks

Created a dynamic library which attaches some external CSS & JS thru `hook_library_info_build` hook and this depends on a dynamic config values set by a config form. So whenever that config form saved, how can I make sure the library info is up to date and latest? and users don't have to always do a complete cache rebuild.

Additionally is it possible to clear(or rebuild) just one library definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, searching thru core services found this. We can clear all the library definitions like this.

```
\Drupal::service('library.discovery')->clearCachedDefinitions();
```

See Drupal Reference of this method: [Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Asset%21LibraryDiscovery.php/function/LibraryDiscovery%3A%3AclearCachedDefinitions/8.9.x)

Calling this function `Clears static and persistent library definition caches.`